# get Site Permission for a web

Tags: permissions

I got the following code working but it does not give me Roles and Groups. Is the syntax I am using good?

```
$webUrl = "http://IVR.cisco.com/Sites/Research/VB3343"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl

foreach ($user in $web.SiteUsers){ 
                            #do not list System account sharepoynt\system 
                            if ($user.Loginname.StartsWith("SHAREPOINT\")) {continue} 
                            $data = @{ 
                                        #"Site" = $site.Url 
                                        "Web Url" = $web.Url 
                                        "Web Name" = $web.Title 
                                        "Username" = $user.Loginname 
                                        "Fullname" = $user.Name 
                                        "Roles" = $user.Roles 
                                        "Groups" = $user.Groups 
                            } 
                                    New-Object PSObject -Property $data 
                                    }
$web.dispose()
```

Comment: Do you get the Groups by executing this:

$users = $web.SiteUsers
$users | % { $_.Groups }

Comment: That did not help. I am positive someone already has a PS for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to massage the following code but it works for me.

```
$webUrl = "http://IVR.cisco.com/Sites/Research/VB3343"
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
Get-SPUser -Web $Web | select UserLogin, @{name="Exlicit given roles";expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name="Roles given via groups";expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}},Groups | format-Table -auto
# Get-SPUser -Web $Web | select UserLogin, @{name="Exlicit given roles";expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name="Roles given via groups";expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}},Groups | out-gridview
# Get-SPUser -Web $Web | select UserLogin, @{name="Exlicit given roles";expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name="Roles given via groups";expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}},Groups | export-csv c:\test.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

The MSDN article on [SPRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sprole.aspx) (the object returned from SPUser.Roles) says that it is obsolete and you should use the [SPRoleDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.sproledefinition.aspx) from the SPWeb object instead. The other alternative is SPRoleAssignment.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. Same thing applies for Groups too?

Comment: No. If the Groups member isn't giving you what you need, you can try looping through the groups on the SPWeb(s) and check ContainsCurrentUser. There is an almost complete example at http://chrissyblanco.blogspot.com/2007/07/determining-whether-user-is-member-of.html which would need a slight update for use in PowerShell